# The statistical test for the change and the statistical test for percentage change do not agree

Tags: r, t-test

```
    mydata<-structure(list(Before = c(24.6, 17, 18.9, 14.6, 16.5, 20.3, 21.6, 
14.1, 18.9, 21.1, 25.4, 14.4, 23.8, 20, 24.5, 25.7, 20.4, 19.4, 
14.7, 17.4, 19.8, 23.3, 20.1, 17.3, 21.2, 17.5, 18.9, 20.3, 17.8
), After = c(20.4, 16.6, 20.7, 17.3, 20.4, 19.8, 22.6, 15.9, 
20, 19.1, 28.4, 16.2, 26.8, 20.4, 26.2, 20.4, 19.8, 19.3, 16, 
20.4, 16.6, 24.1, 24.1, 19.5, 22.4, 21.8, 18.5, 21.9, 16.6)), row.names = c(NA, 
-29L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is paired data of about 30 individuals. I want to test if the change is significantly different from 0 but also the percentage change.

The change is 0 at time before

```
mydata$pourcent_evol_0<-
  ((mydata$Before-
      mydata$Before)/
     mydata$Before)*100
```

Below the % change at time After:

```
mydata$pourcent_evol_1<-
  ((mydata$After -
     mydata$After)/
  mydata$After)*100
```

Then I test if the percentage of change is different from 0

```
t.test(mydata$pourcent_evol_1,
   mydata$pourcent_evol_0, paired = T)

Paired t-test

data:  mydata$pourcent_evol_1 and mydata$pourcent_evol_0
t = 2.2347, df = 28, p-value = 0.0336
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4039322 9.2861680
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
                4.84505
```

I also test the absolute change by

```
t.test(mydata$After,
       mydata$Before, paired = T)

Paired t-test

    data:  mydata$After and mydata$Before
    t = 1.7932, df = 28, p-value = 0.08375
    alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
    95 percent confidence interval:
     -0.1113977  1.6769149
    sample estimates:
    mean of the differences 
                  0.7827586
```

Sorry for my silly question, I know that my calculations for the percentage of change most likely have an effect on the difference in significance between the two tests, but I'm a little embarrassed to have differing conclusions. I was expecting to have either both tests significant or both not significant. Can someone give me a more reasonable explanation

Answer (score 2):

This is because percent change and absolute change really are different questions, so there is no reason to expect that the answers would have to be the same.  This may be easier to see with a much simplified example.

Let's look at a simple case with data on just you and me.  At the beginning of our experiment I can lift 50 pounds and you can lift 100 pounds.  We both exercise and get stronger, in fact we both improve by 50%, so I can now lift 75 pounds and you can lift 150 pounds (you still lift double what I can).  So the percent change is identical, but you can lift 50 more pounds than you did before, while I only improved by 25 pounds, so the absolute differences are different even though the percentage was identical.

We can go the other way as well.  Start with 50 and 100 again, but this time we both improve by an absolute difference of 25 pounds.  I can now lift 75 pounds which is a 50% improvement, but you only improved 25% at lifting 125 pounds, so our absolute differences are the same, but the percentage improvements are different because we started at different points.

With real data it is not quite as obvious, but if you have groups starting at different places, then percent and absolute changes can be quite different.